# Suggestions to block mail relay attempts

Tags: centos, email, postfix

I'm running postfix on CentOS and I'm properly rejecting relay mail requests, but my server is constantly... CONSTANTLY... receiving requests to relay mail. So, the mail logs fill up (not a huge problem with log rotation and such) and the server is always running at a slightly higher load than I'd like it to be. The scripts trying to send all these emails are pretty stupid because it just keeps trying hundreds or thousands of times.

Is there a good way that I can detect and automatically block the IP addresses which are trying to mass-relay through my machine? I'm assuming I would need to cut them off at the iptables level so they can't connect at all.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Fail2Ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/). It watches the logfiles and uses iptables to block the host if it finds specific lines in the logfiles.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out and give it a try in the next day or two.

Answer (score 1):

Also You can configure postscreen http://www.postfix.org/POSTSCREEN_README.html , but You need use postscreen only for MX, not for clients.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you're actually expecting to deal with inbound SMTP traffic, you'll want to set some limits as to how `postfix/smtpd` behaves towards clients.

http://www.postfix.org/TUNING_README.html#conn_limit is a good brief overview.

These are the settings I tend to use.

```
#SMTPd limits
smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 10
smtpd_client_new_tls_session_rate_limit = 5
smtpd_client_recipient_rate_limit = 60
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 10
```

If the server isn't supposed to receive mail at all, you can disable `smtpd` by commenting it out in `$(postconf -h config_directory)/master.cf`.

Answer (score 0):

If your host is not a mail relay you can block the port 25 altogether:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP 
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 25 -j DROP 
service iptables save 
service iptables restart
```